# Adding white space after ggplots using grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm creating ggplots in a loop and then using grid.arrange to plot each of my figures on one page in a lattice-type graph.  The problem I have is that I have a border around each figure and they merge together when I plot them.  Does anyone know how to add white space between the figures.  I've looked for information about figure padding and also toyed around with trying to add blank geom_rect between my plots, but so far no luck.  Some simplified code is provided below.  Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
p = vector("list", 3) #List for arranging grid

for(ii in 1:3){
  p[[ii]] = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg))+
    geom_point()+
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', size = 2))
}
do.call("grid.arrange", c(p, ncol=1))
```

Comment: I realize that not everyone is a native English speaker. Do you perhaps mean that you want "all of your plots on one page"? Also wondering why you wouldn't use the `facet_grid` function within ggplot2?

Comment: I'm from NJ and live in CA so definitely am a native English speaker - just misspoke by calling a plot a figure.  I'm actually writing this collection of plots to a one-page pdf and when researching how to do this, most of what I found pointed to grid.arrange.  I'm sure there are plenty of other ways, including facet_grid, but is there something about that particular direction that would lend itself to solving the actual problem I posed.

Comment: So you do want all of your plots on a single page.

Comment: Have you tried padding the individual plots using `plot.margin`? This can be specified inside `theme`. It should work fine with `grid.arrange`.

Comment: @BondedDust Yes I want to plot on a single page.

Comment: @SimonG  Yes, I had tried this.  If you add "+theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,0.5,0.5),"in"))" to the above code snippet, you will see that the plot.background is drawn around whatever margins I set.  I tried negative numbers and switching the order of these options too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried quite a few different efforts to get the viewports to be smaller within a 3 x 1 layout and finally realized that just adding some blank space with narrow heights in the 5 x 1 layout was pretty easy:

```
Layout <- grid.layout(nrow = 5, ncol = 1, 
                      heights=c(1, .1, 1, .1, 1) )
# could have written code to alternate heights or widths with gaps
grid.show.layout(Layout)
vplayout <- function(...) {  # sets up new page with Layout
     grid.newpage()
     pushViewport(viewport(layout = Layout))
 }

subplot <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x,
     layout.pos.col = y)

mmplot <- function(p=p) { # could make more general
     vplayout()
     print(p[[1]], vp = subplot(1, 1 ))
     print(p[[2]], vp = subplot(3, 1))
     print(p[[3]], vp = subplot(5, 1 ))
 }

mmplot(a, z)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the information.  This is great and I was able to easily implement it in my actual code.  One thing I don't understand is the input variables in the mmplot function.  The variables a and b don't appear to be used so why could they not be left blank like you did for vplayout(...)?

Comment: You probably can simplify. I took some existing code and had made several unsuccessful effort to make it fit this purpose. So  there probably is junk in there.

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, this [experimental version of gtable](https://github.com/baptiste/gtable/blob/master/R/arrange.r) offers a similar interface to grid.arrange,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

lp <- replicate(3, qplot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10)) + 
                     theme(plot.background=element_rect(size = 3, colour="black")),
                simplify = FALSE)

lg <- lapply(lp, ggplotGrob)
g <- do.call(gtable_arrange, c(lg, ncol=1, draw=FALSE))
g <- gtable_add_rows(g, heights = unit(1, "line"), pos = 1)
g <- gtable_add_rows(g, heights = unit(1, "line"), pos = 3)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```